# Why there are several version strings depicting BIOS version in Win32_BIOS class?

Tags: .net, bios

Using `ManagementObjectSearcher` I am accessing BIOS version by:

```
var managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS")
(string[])managementObjectSearcher["BIOSVersion"];
```

I get 3 BIOS versions:

```
LENOVO - 1520
N1EE79W (1.52)
Lenovo - 1520
```

Which version name is "the most valid" and why there are 3?

I found this info, but it doesn't explain the reason behind multiple versions.

> BIOSVersion
>
> Data type: string array
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Array of the complete system BIOS information. In many computers there
>   can be several version strings that are stored in the registry and
>   represent the system BIOS information.

Comment: The `PrimaryBIOS` property looks quite promising, but you may want to change your code to check all properties rather than just the `BIOSVersion` to see how else they differ.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This property is a Boolean, there is also `SMBIOSVersion` and I think this gives dependable information, but the question is about why there are 3 depictions of BIOS version.